# No such property: clean for class groovy.lang.Binding

Tags: maven, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I created a Groovy script for Jenkins, where I am building my project with Maven:

```
node {
  mvn clean install
}
```

However, I am getting:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: clean for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

So what's the correct syntax for cleaning and installing with Maven?

Answer (score 1):

From https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Maven+Plugin:

```
node{
    ...

    withMaven(
            maven: 'M3',
            mavenSettingsConfig: 'maven-settings-for-gameoflife',
            mavenLocalRepo: '.repository') {

        // Run the maven build
        sh "mvn clean install"
    }
}
```

E.g. You need to use the `withMaven` step and then do a native batch or bat command to build. The `withMaven` step makes sure that `mvn` is on the PATH when calling `sh` or `bat`.

Note that you need to set up maven in your Jenkins installation first.

Or, if you already have `mvn` on path on the computer where Jenkins is running, then simply run:

```
node {
  sh "mvn clean install"
}
```

or if you're on windows:

```
node {
  bat "mvn clean install"
}
```